# How to inverse Y axis

Tags: coordinate-system, sqlite, vector-grid, mapcache

I have a SQLlite database containing cached tiles with X,Y,Z fields and I want to use it in MapCache.
My Y field  is appearing upside down in Google tile index but I want to inverse it like this:

```
http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/
```

I'm searching for a way to use my databse in Mapcache or inverse Y field in database to adapt tile indexes with mapcache tile index.

Comment: What is the question? Are you looking to modify the database, or to come up with some configuration option for MapCache, or something else? Is your database really mbtiles or geopackage, or something else you've created or received?

Comment: Whichever it is possible. edit database or config mapcache.
I recived a .gmdb databse contain tiles from my Employer.

Comment: Please edit the question with those details.

Comment: What do you mean by "tils load hardly"? When you speak of "zooming" and "clicked area", which client are you using?

Comment: Can you apply your solution as an Answer rather than an edit to your Question, and then research/ask your new question separately, please?

Comment: @BradHards 
Tiles load slowly. and i use mapcache demo as client.

Comment: @PolyGeo i'm trying to apply my answer, but i can't see answer button.

Comment: Your question has been re-opened so that you can apply your answer now.  If you are able to improve your question with some of the clarifications you provided as comments at the same time then that will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**I solve my problem with editing database and inverse Y field :**

1. create 2 copy of original table(contain personal data).
2. sort 1st copy of table with Z,X,Y ACE and add a newID.
3. sort 2nd copy of table with Z,X ACE and Y DESC and add a newID.
4. update Y filed of 1st table with Y of 2nd table where newID=newID.

now i have a table (1st copy) same as original table with inversed Y value.

5. finally delete rows of Table created by mapcache and update that with my data.

**Note :**
this database works with mapcache with correct position of tiles but tils load slowly and zooming does not work properly(Zooms on area with distance of clicked area). I use mapcache demo as client.